# How to make sure radio button is selected

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, radio-button

I'm doing an experiment, where I present stimuli to participants and ask them questions after each stimulus. I have four questions, each in a separate frame. The answer to each question is selecting one of seven radiobuttons. I have a button also in a separate frame for saving the values of the selections and present the next stimulus. The issue here is that if a participant forgot to select one of the radiobutton, the value of that button would be saved as 0 and I want to avoid that. I tried to make a condition to only enable the next stimulus button only if all radiobuttons were selected and I failed. Is there a way to that?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import PIL.Image 
import PIL.ImageTk
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *

def present(tacton):
    qual_frame = tk.LabelFrame(group, padx=30, pady=30)
    qual_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)


    urgency_frame = tk.LabelFrame(qual_frame, text="How Urgent was the 
    stimulus?", padx=15, pady=30, font = "Verdana 14")
    urgency_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
    urgency  = tk.IntVar()
    Radiobutton(master=urgency_frame, text="1 (Not at all)          ", 
    variable=urgency , value=1, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Radiobutton(master=urgency_frame, text="2                       ", 
    variable=urgency , value=2, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=1)
    Radiobutton(master=urgency_frame, text="3                       ", 
    variable=urgency , value=3, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=2)
    Radiobutton(master=urgency_frame, text="4 (Neutral)             ", 
    variable=urgency , value=4, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=3)
    Radiobutton(master=urgency_frame, text="5                       ", 
    variable=urgency , value=5, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=4)
    Radiobutton(master=urgency_frame, text="6                       ", 
    variable=urgency , value=6, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=5)
    Radiobutton(master=urgency_frame, text="7 (Very much)", variable=urgency , 
    value=7, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=6) 

    annoyance_frame = tk.LabelFrame(qual_frame, text="How Annoying was the 
    stimulus?", padx=15, pady=30, font = "Verdana 14")
    annoyance_frame.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    annoyance = tk.IntVar()
    Radiobutton(master=annoyance_frame, text="1 (Not at all)          ", 
    variable=annoyance, value=1, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Radiobutton(master=annoyance_frame, text="2                       ", 
    variable=annoyance, value=2, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=1)
    Radiobutton(master=annoyance_frame, text="3                       ", 
    variable=annoyance, value=3, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=2)
    Radiobutton(master=annoyance_frame, text="4 (Neutral)             ", 
    variable=annoyance, value=4, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=3)
    Radiobutton(master=annoyance_frame, text="5                       ", 
    variable=annoyance, value=5, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=4)
    Radiobutton(master=annoyance_frame, text="6                       ", 
    variable=annoyance, value=6, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=5)
    Radiobutton(master=annoyance_frame, text="7 (Very much)",  
    variable=annoyance, value=7, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=6) 


    valence_frame = tk.LabelFrame(qual_frame, text = 'How Pleasant was the 
    stimulus?', padx = 15, pady = 30, font = "Verdana 14")
    valence_frame.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    valence = tk.IntVar()
    Radiobutton(master=valence_frame, text="1 (Not at all)          ", 
    variable=valence, value=1, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Radiobutton(master=valence_frame, text="2                       ", 
    variable=valence, value=2, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=1)
    Radiobutton(master=valence_frame, text="3                       ", 
    variable=valence, value=3, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=2)
    Radiobutton(master=valence_frame, text="4 (Neutral)             ", 
    variable=valence, value=4, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=3)
    Radiobutton(master=valence_frame, text="5                       ", 
    variable=valence, value=5, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=4)
    Radiobutton(master=valence_frame, text="6                       ", 
    variable=valence, value=6, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=5)
    Radiobutton(master=valence_frame, text="7 (Very much)",  variable=valence, 
    value=7, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=6) 


    arousal_frame = tk.LabelFrame(qual_frame, text = 'How Exciting was the 
    stimulus?', padx = 15, pady = 30, font = "Verdana 14")
    arousal_frame.grid(row=15, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    arousal = tk.IntVar()
    Radiobutton(master=arousal_frame, text="1 (Not at all)          ", 
    variable=arousal, value=1, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Radiobutton(master=arousal_frame, text="2                       ", 
    variable=arousal, value=2, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=1)
    Radiobutton(master=arousal_frame, text="3                       ", 
    variable=arousal, value=3, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=2)
    Radiobutton(master=arousal_frame, text="4 (Neutral)             ", 
    variable=arousal, value=4, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=3)
    Radiobutton(master=arousal_frame, text="5                       ", 
    variable=arousal, value=5, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=4)
    Radiobutton(master=arousal_frame, text="6                       ", 
    variable=arousal, value=6, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=5)
    Radiobutton(master=arousal_frame, text="7 (Very much)",  variable=arousal, 
    value=7, font = "Verdana 12").grid(row=0, column=6) 



    next_frame = tk.LabelFrame(group, padx=20, pady=20)
    next_frame.grid(row=6, column=1)

    Next_Stimulus = tk.Button(master=next_frame, text="Next Stimulus",  
    bg="green", padx=20, pady=20, width=20, font = "Verdana 12")
    Next_Stimulus.pack()



    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include any imports and test data needed for it to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can let the button be active at all times and check for conditions when you press it, only going to the next stimulus if all variables are set:

```
if all([urgency.get(), annoyance.get()] ... etc):
    # go to next stimulus
```

Or you can trace changes in the IntVars and enable button only when all are set. For each IntVar set up a trace:

```
urgency.trace('w', enable_button)
```

Then check IntVar states in the callback function:

```
def enable_button(*args):
    if all([urgency.get(), annoyance.get()] ... etc):
        Next_Stimulus.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
```